# php - using optional arguments in php

Tags: php

Suppose I have a function defined as following :

```
public function test($title, $body, $role = 0, $place = 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

so, when i call the function like this :

```
test('myname', 'sometext', third_arg);
```

I want 'third_arg' to be the argument for $place and no argument for $role.
I also don't know which of the $role or $place will have a value passed when the function is called everytime. 
How do I pass the argument for $place ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass 0 OR null in 3rd argument:

```
test('myname', 'sometext', 0 ,third_arg);
```

OR

```
test('myname', 'sometext', '' ,third_arg);
```

Comment: better to send 0 instead of empty string. Since the default value is set to 0

Comment: .. Or you can also use the boolean `false`

Answer (score 0):

As the default value for third argument is 0 just pass the value 0 to the third. 
e.g:
`test('myname', 'sometext', 0,third_arg) ;`